# Method setProgress must be called from the UI Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Im trying set the progressbar via AsyncTask. But i have a little problem.

My code is here;

```
    public  class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {


        try {
            //CreateDownloadTransactionInPanel(1);
            long total = 0;
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if(file.exists()){
                //6829809
                deneme = file.length();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-"); // indirmemiÅŸse atamaz

            }

            connection.connect();
            RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            if (file.length() > 0) {
                output.seek(deneme);
                total=deneme;

            }

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            int lastcount = 0;


            while ((count = input.read(data,0,4096)) != -1) {

                if (isCanceled) {
                    downloadresult = false;
                    break;
                }

                if (intCheck()) {
                    total += count;
                    downloadresult = true;
                    ProgBarCount = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                    if (ProgBarCount > lastcount) {
                        lastcount = ProgBarCount;
                        publishProgress(Integer.toString(ProgBarCount));
                        pBar.setProgress(ProgBarCount);

                    }
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                else {
                    downloadresult = false;
                    break;
                }


            } //--While Son--

            output.close();
            input.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exmessage = e.getMessage().toString();
            downloadresult = false;
        }
        return null;
    } // doinBackSON


    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage

        mBuilder.setProgress(100, Integer.parseInt(progress[0]), false);
        mBuilder.setContentText("Şuan İşlemde : %" + Integer.parseInt(progress[0]) + "");
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String downloadpath) {

        if (exmessage != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hata:"+exmessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (downloadresult == true) {

            if (file.exists() && lenghtOfFile == (int) file.length()) {

                Toast.makeText(DownloadActivity.this, "DOSYA INDIRILDI VE YUKLEMEYE HAZIR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DOSYA YOK YADA EKSIK INDIRILDI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            CreateDownloadTransactionInPanel(2);
            scheduleNotificationWithTickButton(); // Tick Button
            RedirectRebootActivity(); // Burda hata olabilir


        } //--True Son


        else // False BaÅŸlangÄ±Ã§

        {
            mNotifyManager.cancel(2219);

            //scheduleNotificationWithResumeButton(); Devam button

        }

    }


}
```

Android studio say: that method `setProgress` must be called from the UI thread.

this line `pBar.setProgress(ProgBarCount);`

is it possible? , Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `PublishProgress`

This fires a call to the onProgressUpdate method in the AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }
```

Do your UI manipulation in this method

Answer (score -2):

```
@Overide
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }
```

you can use this

Comment: duplicate of my answer which is already accepted. I guess you downvoted mine too?

Comment: really sorry, i had opened multiple questions at a time and i was answering some other question, and obviously the page didnt refresh and so couldnt see your answer. Also, nobody intentionally post the same answers, so act maturely and stop crying, and stop downvoting others answer, nobody does it purposely

Comment: I haven't downvoted any answers and am not crying. Only thought it was you as the downvote came in at the exact time your answer was posted. By the way, the page auto-updates so you can see if an answer has already been posted. you may want to refresh the page in future to avoid adding noise if you are leaving questions open without answering them right away. The last question you answered was 45 minutes before this one.

Comment: See again crying for a single vote, please come above it, moreover, i think you are a coder and to analyse some issues you need to setup the code in the IDE and try and test the same for issue and then it can be resolved, doing the same thing and that is y took some more time as the issue didnt resolve, currently also answering a question in which i might have to generate a whole layout and sorry but creating a layout does not take 5 mins or 10 mins for me atleast. Also, just for your clarity, i didnt downvote it, i might now

Comment: Also, just for some more clarity, the page does auto refresh but it doesnt show the answer, it just shows a horizontal divider with a tag "1 answer" and does not show the whole answer, but that too didnt pop up for me, may be my browser had some problem, that is my bad and i am sorry for it, but it was unintentional. Moreover, such things happen, even many of my answers have the same thing that people have given same answer after me, that doesnt mean i go and downvote them too, some solution have common answer and there is nothing you or i can do about it

Comment: For the record, I asked a question. It wasn't an accusation but I can handle the hit to my rep. I don't care about the vote. I'm trying to help educate new users and prevent some of the rubbish that appears on here such as duplicate answers. From the aggressive tone of your comments I guess I offended you so I apologise if that is the case.

Comment: Sorry Kuffs i already apologized in the first message only but things got a bit on the wrong track, due to some technical glitch on my side, lets move ahead, once again i didnt do it intentionally. I didnt downvote it though, i am upvoting it now, tried but not taking my vote, as some more time has passed i think, it will let me upvote, if you kind off do some editing in it

Comment: Guys, Are you serious?